# JUnit Test - Class invokes methods in other class

Tags: java, class, unit-testing, junit

I have a class player which has a method

```
 feedPet(Pet p1, Food f1){
 p1.eat(f1) 
 }
```

So the feedPet invokes the pets eat method, the eat method then adjusts the pets hunger level.

To test this I need create a player and food object in my jUnit test case.

I then test that its working with a simple

```
 assertEquals(p1.getHunger,3);
```

p1 is the pet object I have created in the player test case.

My question is , is what I am doing appropriate? and am I testing my player class correctly?

Really Its testing if the eat method for the pet works but I also need to check that the feedPet method works for the player as well.

Any thoughts or advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do ideally is to create two test files -one for Pet class that tests its eat method and another for player class which tests feedPet Method.

When you write

```
assertEquals(p1.getHunger,3);
```

I hope hunger is the instance variable that was set under eat method of pet class, which as per your expectation is 3. If that's the case you are on right path

Comment: Yes hunger is a variable of the pet class. By taking your advice I would be doing exactly as I have done above but then additionally testing the eat method in pet as well, where I would only require creating a food object and pet object no player. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your test looks something like that

```
@Test
public void player_should_feed_a_pet() {
    Food f1 = givenFoodWithHungerReductionOf(1);
    Pet p1 = givenPetWithHunger(4);
    player.feedPet(p1, f1);
    assertEquals(p1.getHunger(), 3);
}
```

It is a good test. You're not really testing the `Pet.eat()` method, but the correct interactions between `Player` and `Pet`.

You might also need a separate test for `Pet` class to cover more cases.