# What's the best way to unit test classes that delegate the work to others?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have a question about how best to tackle JUnit testing of a top level class. Imagine I have a class, SomeWriter, that has a method that reformats a String and writes it to a stream. The method doesn't actually do the work but instead delegates it to a member object that actually does the real work. I've summarised this in the class below.

```
public class SomeWriter {
public void writeReformattedDataToStream(OutputStream outStream, String message) {
        myReformatter.DoTheActualWorkAndWriteDataToStream(outStream, message);
}
}
```

Now in this hypothetical example, I've already written my unit tests for the myReformatter class and I've demonstrated that myReformatter works. My question is, how should I tackle the unit testing of the writeReformattedDataToStream in SomeWriter?

If I were black box testing, I would need to write the same test as I applied to the myReformatter class because I wouldn't know how it implements the task. However, unit testing is really white box testing, so is it valid for the test merely to ensure that myReformatter is being correctly called?

The bottom line is should my test of writeReformattedDataToStream effectively repeat the test of myReformatter, or mock myReformatter and just check it's being called correctly?

I appreciated this is similar to [JUnit Test - Class invokes methods in other class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16352324/junit-test-class-invokes-methods-in-other-class)

Answer (score 6):

Immediate delegation like this usually falls under the heading of "too simple to test", but if you have some absolute requirement for it, then you need to mock your `OutputStream` (using EasyMock or a similar tool) and `myReformatter` and verify that the delegate calls the appropriate method.

Comment: why should he mock OutputStream?

Comment: If he's going to test this method, he has to make sure that it passes `outStream` on to the delegate and doesn't replace it with some other `OutputStream`; passing in a mock is the easiest way I know to confirm that `write` gets called on the same object.

Comment: Thanks. Interesting that there seems to be a feeling that it's too simple to test. I've been trying a TDD approach to the design which is why I finished up with a lot of tests for methods I normally wouldn't have bothered with. I get a horrible feeling now that someone's going to tell me that if I wrote the test first I wouldn't know the implementation.

Answer (score 4):

As chrylis says, you should not test this method.

There is actually nothing to test.

If you write a test case that tests that the delegate / service is called, then your test is bound to the implementation of the tested method.

So any change in the implementation of the method would require to change the test; and I am sure that you do not want that.

Answer (score 3):

Try injection. For testing purposes you could inject your own implementation of the myReformater class that simply checks that the method was called correctly and returns. Then you are testing your test class in isolation.